# Custom Web Service - CurrentCulture is incorrect

Tags: 2013, web-services, localization

I have created a custom WCF Web Service in a SharePoint solution and deployed it to a SharePoint 2013 environment. The svc file is located in the ISAPI folder and I am able to call it and use it successfully.

However, I am having issues when working with dates within the service. The CultureInfo.CurrentCulture is returning as "en-US", when it should be "en-GB". I have checked the identity that the application pool is running as and the location settings within Control Panel (and registry settings) are set to en-GB / UK.

I have tried adding `<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB" />` to both the web.config located in the ISAPI folder and the web.config located in the Web Application virtual directory, but this hasn't had any effect either.

Can I make any changes that would have SharePoint and the web service run under the en-GB culture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I had tried to change the regional settings everywhere with the exception of within the actual site settings (the existence of which I was unaware, previously assuming that regional settings would be based on the server settings of the farm).

Once changed on the site (via Site Settings - Regional Settings), the web service picked up the correct culture.